# UITableView cells blank

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm trying to recover after accidentally deleting my .m file.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong that is causing my cells to all render blank?

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}
@end
```

### .m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "Shared.h"
#import "Message.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Foo"; 
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of rows %i", [[Shared sharedInstance].messages count]]);
    //this comes back as 10
    return [[Shared sharedInstance].messages count];
}
```

Update:

I have it pinned down to a weird problem.  In the following, i logs out as 10, but if I return i the rows show blank.  If I return 10 as shown below, it works.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger i = [[Shared sharedInstance].messages count];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of rows %i", i]);
    return 10;
}
```

Another update:

Ok, I've gotten closer.  It seems that although reloaddata is getting called when I walk through with debugger, it doesn't seem to be properly reloading.  That's why the hard coded number worked if I used a hardcoded sample string for each row.  The first time it gets loaded, the number of rows would be zero and since reloaddata isn't working, the next time it gets loaded it didn't update to 10 rows.
    In case someone wonders if I'm connected to delegate and datasource.

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Can be so many things. Did you hook up the tableview delegate and datasource properties?

Comment: Yes, they're attached to files owner and I set the xib view to UITableView.

Comment: Did you set the number of sections in tableview to 1 in the delegate method?

Comment: I hadn't but I just did with the following: `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}`

Comment: Does the table actually returns any cell (are the returned cells visible in the table) or do you just see an empty table? If cells are returned, did you try to change the font color of the textLabel?

Comment: I have it pinned down to a weird problem as described in the update above.  Even though i returns as 10 when I log it above, the labels don't show up unless I set return to the number 10.

Comment: Solved! In a previous XIB I had the wrong name listed for the XIB name. I'm not sure why it wasn't producing an error and only seemed to be having an effect on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are using an XIB, that your connections are made and that they point to a `UITableView`.

Also, when you use UITableViewController, theres no need to use the `<..Delegate,..Datasource>` protocols.

Comment: Done, done, and done.  I think it has to do with the edit that I put in.  If I return a number rather than a variable that is an int with a number stored in it, it works.  Unfortunately, I have to make it a variable of course.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten closer and posted another update in case this helps.  Reload doesn't seem to be working as advertised.

Comment: You actually don't even need the XIB if you aren't adding any extra outlets, so you could just delete the XIB to reduce confusion.

Comment: Solved!  In a previous XIB I had the wrong name listed for the XIB name.  I'm not sure why it wasn't producing an error and only seemed to be having an effect on this one.